# where to find downloaded library of sbt?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

Where does sbt put the downloaded jar? I'm trying to ask sbt to download all dependencies and put them under lib/ directory so I can use them with the ScalaIDE, however after I ran `sbt compile` successfully I don't know where to find these downloaded .jars

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All new SBT versions (after `0.7.x`) by default put the downloaded JARS into the `.ivy2` directory in your home directory.

If you are using Linux, this is usually `/home/<username>/.ivy2/cache`.

If you are using Windows, this is usually `c:\Users\<username>\.ivy2\cache`.

EDIT:

Here's an example from one of my projects,
in which I define an SBT task that copies the dependencies into the target folder.
You can place this code into your `project/Build.scala` project definition file.
You should have something like this in your project definition file (more info at www.scala-sbt.org):

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import Process._

object MyProjectBuild extends Build {
```

The following code copies all your libraries to a `deploy/libz` subdirectory,
by defining a `deploy` task that captures your program artifact and all its classpath dependencies:

```
val deployKey = TaskKey[Unit](
  "deploy",
  "Deploys the project in the `deploy` subdirectory."
)

val deployTask = deployKey <<= (artifactPath in (Compile, packageBin), dependencyClasspath in Compile) map {
  (artifact, classpath) =>
  val deploydir = new File("deploy")
  val libzdir = new File("deploy%slib".format(File.separator))

  // clean old subdirectory
  deploydir.delete()

  // create subdirectory structure
  deploydir.mkdir()
  libzdir.mkdir()

  // copy deps and artifacts
  val fullcp = classpath.map(_.data) :+ artifact
  def lastName(file: File) = if (file.isFile) file.getName else file.getParentFile.getParentFile.getParentFile.getName
  for (file <- fullcp) {
    println("Copying: " + file + "; lastName: " + lastName(file))
    if (file.isFile) IO.copyFile(file, (libzdir / lastName(file)).asFile);
    else IO.copyDirectory(file, (libzdir / lastName(file)))
  }
} dependsOn (packageBin in Compile)
```

Comment: Thx. But is there any way I can tell SBT directly download the dependencies into my /lib directory?

Comment: I added an example, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 14):

In more recent versions (1.3+), `sbt` has switched to Coursier instead of Ivy for fetching dependencies.

The Coursier cache [varies by operating system](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cache#location). According to the linked docs, the default values are:

> - on Linux, ~/.cache/coursier/v1
> - on OS X, ~/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1.
> - on Windows, %LOCALAPPDATA%\Coursier\Cache\v1

You can also find the value with `show csrCacheDirectory` from inside SBT.

Answer (score 4):

I find the sbt dependency from http://mvnrepository.com/

for example, you want to find `MySQL Java Connector`, you can search form the search box, and choose a version you like, then you will see `sbt` tag:

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34"
```

if you want to find the downloaded jars, in windows is `C:\Users\<userName>\.ivy2\cache`

in linux is `~/.ivy2/cache`

good luck

Answer (score 2):

The reference below is useful for sbt.

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Launcher-Configuration.html

You can find sbt.ivy.home is the parameter and default is ${user.home}/.ivy2/.

> ...
>
> [repositories]   local   typesafe-ivy-releases:
>   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/,
>   [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext],
>   bootOnly   maven-central   sonatype-snapshots:
>   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots
>
> [boot]   directory:
>   ${sbt.boot.directory-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/boot/}
>
> [ivy]   ivy-home: ${sbt.ivy.home-${user.home}/.ivy2/}
>
> ...