# How to change the default location of the jar files downloaded when building scala project using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to scala and learning scala.I am trying to build a scala project using sbt tool.I could figure out that the default location for the jars downloaded while building the scala project is as follows

```
c:\users\<username>\.ivy2\cache
```

Now i want to change the default location. For example i want to download all the jar files to the following location **E:\scalarepo.**

Is there a way to change the default location. I have checked the location of my sbt installation which is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf
```

And see that there is a file by name **sbtconfig.txt** . Is there a property where we can set the location ?

As in maven we can change the location in the **conf/settings.xml** file to make sure the jar files are downloaded to a specific folder instead of the default location which is **${user.home}.m2\repository**

Can you please let me know

1. If there is a property which we can set, if yes what is the property
2. Is it good to change the default location
3. What is the file that we
   need to change

This is one of the link i found [where to find downloaded library of sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094610/where-to-find-downloaded-library-of-sbt) which tells the default location of the jar files downloaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Ivy cache directory per-user or system-wide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142856/how-to-configure-ivy-cache-directory-per-user-or-system-wide). Check @MarkTye answer, it should help