# IntelliJ download the libraries once and use in multiple projects

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, libraries

I have an IntelliJ with Scala plugin intalled on the server. The server is disconnected from the global internet and all the updates can be done ocsasionally only.

Would like to download some libraries once (e.g. Spark libraries, some libraries from Java) and use them in IntelliJ in the multiple projects without need of downloading them, but loading from local direcories. Also it would be great to have a 'full' bundle of libraries (e.g. all Spark libraries) and be able to use only particular classes when it's necessary (e.g. Spark Context only).

TK

P.S. Question is somewhat related to the: [Use Scala on computer without internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545756/use-scala-on-computer-without-internet-connection)

Comment: Consider downloading all the dependencies on a online machine and then copy `~/.ivy2` directory over to offline machine, or create a fat jar using sbt-assembly as suggested in the linked question.

Comment: Is .ivy2 related strictly to the IntelliJ or it's a general purpose hidden directory? Thank you Mario for activity and responsing my set of recent stackoverflow questions. :)

Comment: sbt downloads jars to [`.ivy2`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Ivy+Home+Directory) directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27095198/5205022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarioGalic sugested, the cluse was to move a required libraries to the `~/.ivy2` directory.

Somethimes the case is to add libraries manually in IntelliJ project setup, insted of using SBT or Maven to manage the dependencies.